# How does @UniqueConstraint works?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In the following entity I want to make a unique writes in db but seems it has no effect until I set it up in the db table. Even more - If а I remove that annotation then it still work if it was set in the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "score_record", catalog = "solardb", uniqueConstraints =  { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "topic_id", "user_id" }) })
public class ScoreRecord {
    private Integer recordId;
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer score;
```

So what is actualy the purpose of @UniqueConstraint? Is it works just like like a "reminder"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only like "reminder". If you will generate Database scheme from your classes, DDL for this scheme will contains constraint that you specified in annotation `@UniqueConstraint`.

[JavaDoc for `@UniqueConstraint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html)

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error when you save another ScoreRecord with existing userId/recoreId. the columns will also have constraint key in the database (used in migration and such)